# Query arbitrary/varying URLs with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit to pull down podcast feeds. The feeds come from arbitrary urls but all have a similar format so I'm using retrofit with simplexml to deserialize them. However, I can't get retrofit to make a request to an arbitrary url (with varying hosts and paths) given its more rigid endpoint + api structure. Is there a way I can accomplish this without using a separate networking library?

Comment: Changing `Endpoint` is possible if you change `Endpoint` url value as you need. Regarding the paths I'm not sure.